# Modifying and creating sites in djangos admin app

Tags: python, django

I have to include multiple changes to djangos admin panel, so I decided to fork the django admin app into my own django project.

As I was working with this admin app I recognized, that the site registration and template handling differs from the apps, that are normally created in django.
For instance, I want to keep the old admin index.html template and view, for backup and safety reasons but the landing page should be replaced by a custom page.

For that of course I need to change admin/templates/index.html and /admin/sites.py respectively.

I copied the old index function in admin/sites.py to old_index.py and created a old_index.html in the template folder.

But if I try to reference to old_index.html in my new index.html with

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:old_index' %}">old index</a>
```

I got an NoReverseMatch-Exception thrown. Unfortunately I did not found more information about how the django admin app itself register new views and sites, so an example or description would be helpful.

Creating separate views for the admin app in the distinct other apps in my project is no real option, due the high amount of changes, that need to be done.

The main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'django_project.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('other_app.urls', namespace="other_app")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The admin app itself does not provide a urls.py file and the views.py is exactely the same as in django.contrib.admin I just copied the function index to a new function called old_index, referencing to a template old_index.html.

Maybe the point did not get so clear, as I expected. I copied the whole admin app in my project and want to add a custom defined site to it, regardless where. But I failed to understand how sites and views are registered in the admin app itself, because the way is different from the custom apps you create normally in django.

So, is it possible (and how) to add a custom site in the django.contrib.admin app?

Comment: It would be helpful to add more, such as your `urls.py` (both main and app) and potentially `views.py`. Could you paste that in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create your own AdminSite for custom purposes and keep default as it is. More about this you can find here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf

**Update:**

You need to edit get_urls method of AdminSite class - add:

```
url(r'^$', wrap(self.old_index), name='old_index')
```

to urlpatterns variable. And rename old index method to old_index.

Comment: I considered this, but I don't want to write all functionality for the custom-admin again on my own, so I tried to use and customize the contrib-admin app of django.

Comment: You need to modify get_urls method of AdminSite - look at answer update.

Comment: I did that and referenced to a nee template file but I'm still getting a NoReverseMatch Exception from django. Tor me everything seems to be on the right place.

Comment: I made mistake in url - '^$' have to be changed to some other url. Please try to correct this and try if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, for your update. I changed that and recognized, that my admin app was importing sites and AdminSites still from django.contrib.admin, instead from the local app. When I change the import to the local app, I lose my permissions in the admin app and get the message "You don't have the permissions to edit anything". I will try to figure out, how to fork the admin app correctly to finally answer this question.